# String equality test fails for base64 encoded sha512 digest

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have the following table

```
   Column    |            Type            | Collation | Nullable |
-------------+----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 name        | text                       |           | not null |
 code        | text                       |           | not null |
```

I insert new elements using the following INSERT

```
INSERT INTO table(name, code)
    VALUES('SOMENAME',encode(digest(gen_random_uuid()::text,'sha512'), 'base64')) ;
```

Now when I try to SELECT against the `code` field:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE code='K5HUaRwxsXzkAl3NaWHbBkvnYEK/...';
```

It returns an empty set.

```
----------
(0 rows)
```

The puzzling part is that it seems to break only for **SHA512** *with* **base64** encoding , it works just fine if I use **SHA256** or if I change the encoding to **HEX**.

I have a feeling that it might be a bug, but am I missing something?

Comment: What other system are you getting the comparison base64 value from? base64 encoding can actually vary across platforms/software https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Why would you take a sha512 digest of a random uuid casted to text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 64 bytes, the `sha512` digest is large enough that encoding it in `base64` generates a newline character (LF) in the result (at about 76 characters from the start).

Probably what goes wrong is that newline character not being correctly reinjected in the SELECT query, where you truncated the literal with an ellipsis (so we can't actually see it):

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE code='K5HUaRwxsXzkAl3NaWHbBkvnYEK/...';
```

To inject a newline, you may use the `E'...'` syntax and have `\n` to denote that character.

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE code= E'K5HUaR.....\n...rest of string';
```